# Snap SVG animation slowing down the FPS

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, svg, snap.svg

As you can see on this page: http://www.gigil.it/newroot/index.php//come-doniamo

I have some svg animations done with snap SVG.
The animations are triggered when the element is in the viewport.
And it's basically doing the same animation on all the paths inside the SVG.

Here is the script:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {

        jQuery(".icon-come-doniamo").each(function(){
            //console.log($(this));
            if (jQuery(this).isOnScreen() == true) {
                if (!jQuery(this).hasClass("already-visible")){
                    var $that = jQuery(this);
                    setTimeout(function(){
                    //jQuery(this).addClass("already-visible");
                       var Elemento = $that.find("svg");
                       var iconSnap = Snap("#"+Elemento.attr("id"));
                       var iconPaths = iconSnap.selectAll("path");
                       var delays = 0;
                       var count = 0;

                       iconPaths.forEach(function(elem,i) {
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            //console.log("gegge");
                            var elemDim = elem.getBBox();
                            elem.animate({transform: 'r0,' + elemDim.cx + ',' + elemDim.cy + 's1,1' }, 700, mina.linear );
                        }, delays);
                        delays = delays + 400;
                        count = count + 1;
                       });

                       if (count == iconPaths.length) {
                           //console.log("fattgegge");
                           $that.addClass("already-visible");
                       }
                    },1000);
                }
            }
        });

    });
```

Pretty simple I think, but very often the FPS gets really really low and the animations become super bulky.
I've tried anything, but no big changes.
Any tips?

Comment: It would be useful if you could isolate them into a jsfiddle or similar. You've got a few paths which are all animating at the same time, and its hard to know if thats an issue or not. I'm not sure why you also have 'r0' in your transform. Rotations can cause a large slowdown in transforms of svg (not sure if its optimised if its set to 0 or not). Worth also noting that I think you can do Snap(Elemento) rather than accessing the id, that won't make any difference to speed, just as a slight code optimisation.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by removing the Bounding Box calculations.
Removed the rotation property.

Now it's a lot smoother.

From this:

```
elem.animate({transform: 'r0,' + elemDim.cx + ',' + elemDim.cy + 's1,1' }, 700, mina.linear );
```

to this:

```
elem.animate({transform: 's1,1' }, 700, mina.linear );
```